# Updating the state inside map function using react hooks using spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

How do you update the value inside an array with the useState hook after i used it in a map function?

At the moment i have a handleChange function which works but i want to use the setState() directly inside the onChange in the input field.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([1,2,3]);

{array.map((v,i) => {<input onChange={(e)=>setArray([...array, ...v, e.target.value])}/>})}
```

How do i update the value like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advice against it, because such a one-liner makes the code quite unreadable, in my opinion.

Anyway, here it is...

```
{array.map((v,i) => {
  <input onChange={
    (e)=>setArray(
      [...array.slice(0, i), e.target.value, ...array.slice(i+1)]
    )}
  />
})}
```

---

Given the array `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `i=2` you will have:

- `...array.slice(0, i)` → `[1,2]`
- `e.target.value` → the new value
- `...array.slice(i+1)` → `[4,5]`

Comment: So it's not possible to change the value without slicing? Like we do with an object using the spread operator and then assigning new value to the property